# How do get rid of this resource id error on Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin android. I keep getting this error and have no idea how to get rid of it.

Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'button_1'

This is the code I'm using. The code works when I add a breakpoint to the Button button21 line but I keep getting an error in my visual studio editor. I am trying to use button click to navigate to another page.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Button button21 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_1);
            button21.Click += Button_Click;
        }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        }
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_1" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see button_1 property in the Resources.designer.cs file? If you comment 2 lines of "Button button21" and compile the project, is there any warning?

Comment: public const int button_1 = 2131230760; Found this in Resouces.designer.cs and there are no warnings when I comment those two lines!

Comment: So the resource generator is working fine. The only cause now is the wrong namespace reference. Maybe remove all namespace on top of your Activity.cs file and import again using Alt + Enter

Comment: I tried that and then deleted the button and used a new one and now the code works. No clue what happened there. Thanks for all the help Tri!

Comment: Glad it helped! Sometimes there is ambiguous namespace reference in Xamarin.Android, not sure exactly but better just try

Comment: @ Peter Parker You can post the solution and accept it ,which will help more people .